# Pandas dictionaries to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, python-3.5

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
                                                 Data
0   {'high': 630.99, 'low': 596.57, 'open': 624.79...
1   {'high': 612.55, 'low': 607.06, 'open': 608.52...
2   {'high': 612.40, 'low': 605.92, 'open': 608.23...
...
```

how do I convert it to a dataframe like:

```
  high   low    open   ...
0 630.99 596.57 624.79 ...
1 612.55 607.06 608.52 ...
2 612.40 605.92 608.23 ...
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert `dict` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html), then to `list` and last use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.Data.values.tolist(), index=df.index)
print (df)
     high     low    open
0  630.99  596.57  624.79
1  612.55  607.06  608.52
2  612.40  605.92  608.23
```